# angular comments attributes inside template

Tags: angular, angular-template

Can I comment attribute inside html markup?

I need to do something like that:

```
<hero-detail 
     <!--comments goes here-->
     hero="currentHero">
</hero-detail>
```

But this does not work. How can it be done?

Answer (score 6):

This is invalid HTML. Angular only works with valid HTML.
HTML comments are only allowed outside or inside elements, but not of the element itself.

Answer (score 1):

You can not write comment in the element, but **you can move your comment out of the element** as below:

```
<!-- your comments goes here -->
<hero-detail hero="currentHero">
</hero-detail>
```

Or in the element as:

```
<hero-detail hero="currentHero">
<!-- your comments goes here -->
</hero-detail>
```